# How can i add social share button manually?

Tags: html, share-button

I want to add Social share button manually not from other website, How can I will do it. I have a new site and I use new [free high pr site list](http://www.onlineteamdhaka.com/), Now i need help..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the HTML scripts to the specific button?
An example I found of what I meant can be read here: https://simplesharebuttons.com/html-share-buttons/

Not quite sure if I understod your question correctly, so please do tell me if I'm wrong and I'll try to assist.

Comment: @SagarAhammed No problem, hopefully what I suggested was to any use of you.